# Make a method in Java return a variable initialized in inner class

Tags: java, android, oop, firebase

I have a method

```
public String getUsername(String uid){
       uid= auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference uidRef = mFirebaseuser.child(uid);
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("TAG", ""+dataSnapshot);
                String username=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("what"+databaseError);
            }
        });
        return username;
    }
```

I want `getUsername` to return the string `username` which is initialized in inner class but I don't have access to it, also I cant modify `onDataChange` since its overriden. If I initialize `username` in `getUsername` method before the inner class I have to make it final and then won't be able to set its value in `onDataChange` please help me to get a work around this.

Comment: It is not possible. That's not how callback methods work.

Comment: it is possible as mentioned in the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go, with out having testing it, declare `username` as private variable in your class, like this:

```
private String username = null;
```

then use it another place in class

```
if (username != null){
    //TODO what ever with username
}
```

And in your inner class remove `String` and make your method as void

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Log.d("TAG", ""+dataSnapshot);
    username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you variable username as a global variable and inside annonymouse class give the value and return it

Comment: But it isn't a good practice to declare variables global right? is there any other way?

Comment: this doesn't work, username returned is null. @abdul

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to this is to make a one element array and return the value of it. It's kinda ugly, but it works!

```
public String getUsername(String uid){
   uid= auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

   final String[] username = new String[1]; // final makes it accessible inside the inner class

    DatabaseReference uidRef = mFirebaseuser.child(uid);
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("TAG", ""+dataSnapshot);

    username[0]=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("what"+databaseError);
        }
    });
    return username[0]; 
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, username returned is null. @Infamous

Comment: Are you sure that the event was fired ??  Did the Log got printed in the logcat ??

Comment: Show me the logcat please? or try out ```Log.d("TAG", "Username is "+dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class));```

Comment: @Sanju, What happened when ```Log.d("TAG", "Username is "+dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class));``` is used

Comment: it gives the expected result, in short, it is fired but the value gets back to null after the scope of inner class is over.

Comment: @Sanju, I have no idea why that happens. Try debugging the method, put a breakpoint at ```final String[] username = new String[1];``` and execute each line one by one and see if the username array gets updated and then goes null

Comment: yes, the username array is updated and then goes null, is there a way to overcome this?